# xcode 7.3: how to put a constant in a struct

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to put constants in a struct, but compiler generates error that ";" is missing at the "=".

```
struct {
    int aaa=111;  // error: "expected ; at end of declaration list"
} blah;
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is compiled with at least C++11? (in class member fields initialization is a C++11 feature)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try maybe:

```
int aaa{111};
```

And if you need int as a constant you should probably include the const keyword.

```
const int aaa{111};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize at the time of defining the structure in Obj-C. Initialization is possible at the time of creating instance shown as below.

```
struct Employee {
  int idNumber;
  int age;
};

// create instance
struct Employee emp1;
emp1.idNumber=12345;
emp1.age = 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Objective-C, in an .h file add something like:

```
extern const struct MyStruct {
    int aaa;
} MyStruct;
```

In the .m file:

```
const struct MyStruct MyStruct = {
    .aaa = 1
};
```

`#import` the .h file and use the struct in your code like this:

`if (someInteger == MyStruct.aaa) ...`